# Install Drupal using composer

Tags: 7, installation, composer

I'am trying to install Drupal 7 using composer. Before that I tried to install drupal 8 using composer and it works perfectly.

Now when I try to install D7 using same method it is still installing D8 instead of D7. I set up package repository as mentioned [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies) but still installing D8 only. I tried `$ composer clearcache` also but no difference. Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Checking https://packagist.org/packages/drupal/drupal for the versions available there is NO 7.x version. Drupal 7 has no **composer.json** for this to command to work.

You can use one of the other 2 methods mentioned on https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-manage-drupal-site-dependencies

Using https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project you need to tell the version

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:7.x-dev \
  test-3 --stability dev --no-interaction
```

Using https://github.com/hussainweb/drupal-composer-init you can do

```
composer drupal-init --drupal-7
```

Please note:

- applying core patches seems tricky or even not working. The core tree (whole web root) is deleted then reapplied. But then ie sites/all/modules gets emptied. See

  - https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches/issues/42
  - https://github.com/drupal-composer/preserve-paths/issues/10
  - In https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches/issues/42#issuecomment-288365507 a patch is available but that seems NOT to work 100%

Answer (score 1):

```
$ composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:7.x-dev \
example --stability dev --no-interaction
```

This will copy the drupal-project to the example directory, and download Drupal core and some handy packages. This is a good point to cd into the example directory, run git init , and to then create your initial commit for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Encountering this issue, in the process of upgrading a D7 site to D8, it took me a while to realize that there might be a slightly different question that often is more relevant:

**How would one install D7 with modules, similarly to how one would install D8 with composer?**

By using `drush make` was the answer for me. Unless I'm mistaken, that tool was contemporary with D7 to a much higher degree than composer was.

An easy way to get started is to install drush 8 (make is removed in newer versions) using composer, and then adapt `drush/drush/examples/example.make.yml` to your needs. For more details please see the [documentation](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.x/docs/make.md).

Clearly this is a bad idea for production systems, but that goes for creating new D7 instances today too.